# search and replace using regex

Tags: functions, regex

Hello please I want to search and replace word after `/check/` and make it to be permalink sanitized.
i.e

```
https://example.com/check/Dav,ido Song/ => with https://example.com/dav-ido-song/

https://example.com/check/daV,i'do1/ => https://example.com/dav-i-do1/

https://example.com/check/daV(i'do)/ => https://example.com/dav-i-do/
```

I want to achieve this using  sanitize_title() or sanitize_title_with_dashes() function.

here is my word replacer. I dont know where i am getting it wrong.

```
function emailleftappend($content){

        $findleft = '/check\/(?<=\/)([A-Za-z]+?)(?=\/">)/m';
        $replaceleft = sanitize_title_with_dashes($findleft);

//      $content = preg_replace($findleft, $replaceleft, $content);

    return preg_replace($findleft, $replaceleft, $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'emailleftappend');
```

Gurus in the house please help me out, i am not good in wp.

Comment: It's not working because you are adding this filter to `the_content`. That only filters post content - not the permalink. Look into other hooks for adjusting the permalink.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that passing a regex to [`sanitize_title_with_dashes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/) will work the way you think it will. The function expects a title as its first argument, not a regular expression.

Comment: @Pat J please kindly help me correct it if you have much idea about wp

Comment: @WebElaine, please kindly help me fix if you have idea about it

Comment: Are you trying to replace all the URLs in a post's content, or is this code to be used in some other context?

Comment: just the urls on the post content, so that any post that contain link that has /check/ will be replaced